# How to limit google map view using place id?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

Is it possible to limit google map view using place id?(city)

zoom and view and get lat and lng only limit view.

```
GoogleMap(
      mapType: MapType.normal,
      initialCameraPosition: cameraPosition,
      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
      },
    );
```

Comment: You mean this? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-bounds-restriction

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava yes. thank you. is it possible to use on Flutter

Comment: Should be possible if you are able to integrate maps correctly

Comment: You can do a place details request with the place id, requesting at least the `geometry` field in `fields` which should return a `viewport` which as per the docs *contains the preferred viewport when displaying this place on a map*. You should then be able to use the viewport bounds object as a `cameraTargetBounds` in Flutter.

Comment: @MrUpsidown thank you so much you support. sorry for reply late. It's very helpful for me. I will try and let you know. sorry for again

Comment: That's ok, it's good to give some feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can set bounds and animate the camera with the controller, for example:

```
LatLngBounds getLatLngBounds() {
    //this.points is a List<LatLng> representing vertex of a polygon, it could be a city.
    var maxLat = this.points.map((latlng) => latlng.latitude).reduce(max);
    var maxLng = this.points.map((latlng) => latlng.longitude).reduce(max);
    var minLat = this.points.map((latlng) => latlng.latitude).reduce(min);
    var minLng = this.points.map((latlng) => latlng.longitude).reduce(min);

    return LatLngBounds(
        northeast: LatLng(maxLat, maxLng), southwest: LatLng(minLat, minLng));
  }
```

To animate the camera:

```
...
onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
              try {
                controller.animateCamera(
                    CameraUpdate.newLatLngBounds(getLatLngBounds(), 50)
              } on Exception catch (e) {
                print(e);
              }
            },
...
```

This solution requires you to get a polygon from that specific place id.